# Add Polymer on Sails.js

Tags: javascript, polymer, sails.js

I have been working on a project with Sails.js for 3 months, and I just discovered Polymer which seems pretty cool. I would like to know how to add it to my project, since it seems very different from Bootstrap or Foundation where I only add CSS and JS files.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't currently have Bower installed on your system, you'll need to install that first before Polymer. Then, install Polymer into the `/assets` folder in your Sails application.

Next, open up the `config/routes.js` file and comment out everything in `module.exports.routes {}`. Create an `index.html` file in `/assets`, and let that serve as your app's index page. I'd probably stop using the ejs templating system (assuming you're using it at all) for now, and use sails as a backend api with Polymer handling front end duties.

That should be enough to get everything up and running.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the ejs templating and routing provided by sails and still use polymer, another option would be to configure bower to install to `assets/bower_components`. You can do this by creating a `.bowerrc` file with the following content: `{ "directory" : "assets/bower_components" }`

After you run `bower install` you need to include polymer in your project by placing `<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section of the `layout.ejs` file.

Each polymer component that you want to add can be placed in the `layout.ejs` file. For example, if you wanted to include a paper button, you would place `<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">` in the `<head>` section just after the line including polymer.

Now you can use polymer components in any `.ejs` file that you create. For example:

```
<div>
    My super awesome Polymer project!
    <paper-button raised>raised</paper-button>
</div>
```

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R9oH.png)